# Create logic using PHP

Tags: php

I have form similar to the one below were the text can be edited. I would like to add some logic that would allow edits, and re-edits for 5 minutes. If no re-edit is made you would have to wait 24 hours before the edit

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>
<span>Short Description :</span>
<input type="text" name="shortdesc" size="200" maxlength="1250" value="<? echo"$record->shortdesc";?>" />
</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit listing" />
</form>
```

edit.php

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE list SET shortdesc='$shortdesc' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you log the time the record is inserted? Is that all the code in `edit.php`; looks open to SQL injections.

Comment: I am aware I will need to add a timestamp for reference and filters. The logic steps 1: allow edit after 24 hours, step 2 : Allow edit up to 5 minutes after edit is made step 3: disallow after 5 minutes until 24 hours has passed.

Comment: Use `datediff` and check if the records was editted in whatever ranges you want. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: mysql_* functions are removed from PHP and will no longer work with new PHP. Please try to use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a column for a timestamp then compare the timestamp to the current time to see if edit is allowed. You should also use mysql statements to prevent sql injection.

Comment: The question is how do I write the logic? I have ideas on how this can be accomplished but not sure if they are the most efficient codes.

Comment: Efficiency is overrated. Is your code clear? If so it's better then something convulted but efficient.

Comment: Please supply the code for the logic you have in mind. @NickYoung is spot on, if it works and is readable and decently encapsulated that so it can be changed later without breaking things, it is likely fine. Premature optimization is evil. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization